# How to connect SQL Server 2008 with IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am using Amazon EC2 server, with Windows Server. It has installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and IIS7. I have made a web site, and want to test this web app. But it is not connecting to the SQL Server. I have tried different connection strings. But it is giving this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Cannot open database "Avon" requested
>   by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE'.

I have tried to change it from windows authentication to SQL Server authentication and vice versa. But same error.

My connection string is

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Avon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true;"
```

I have copied `Avon.mdf` and `Avon.ldf` file into `App_data`. I want it to connect either by local server, or by IP address.

I appreciate your answers. 
Thanks

Comment: I got the same problem can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If the identity under which the application is running does not have access to the database, you will need to provide user name and password in the connection string.

Example:
`Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=someuserid;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, That problem has been solved, it was problem with my connection string Data Source=50.17.237.235,1433;Initial Catalog=Avon;User ID=syed;Password=syedali;

Answer (score 0):

You could also try changing your Application pool identiy to a user that has access to the database. or set up asp.net impersonation

Answer (score 0):

Application pool on II7 work in context of user NETWORK SERVICE. In your connection string you have Integrated Security=True.
Solutions:
1) Change connection string to use userId+password
2) Change application pool user - not recommended if you don't understand how it works
3) Allow user NETWORK SERVICE connect to your sql server\data base - not recommended because many others services use this technical account.